# How can I set a numerical variable based on user input

Tags: php

I am currently running into the undefined variable issue when attempting to set a numerical variable based on the user input.

I have previously had the variable assigned just to test out the math logic through selecting an option for headcount with a dropdown menu ex:

```
<option value="Less Than 20">Less Than 20</option>
<option value="Less Than 50">Less Than 50</option>
```

and creating multiple if/else if statements based off what was selected:

```
if($head_count == "Less Than 20"){
            $head_count = 15;
            $taskMeetings_int = $head_count * 1.6;
            $taskMeetings_low = 420 * $taskMeetings_int;
            $taskMeetings_high = 1250 * $taskMeetings_int;
}else if($head_count == "Less Than 50"){
            $head_count = 40;
            $taskMeetings_int = $head_count * 1.6;
            $taskMeetings_low = 420 * $taskMeetings_int;
            $taskMeetings_high = 1250 * $taskMeetings_int;
}
```

but now having trouble using variables when inputting actual numbers to the form with the variable not being defined. I thought setting the variables of `Headcount` and `Square Footage` to `null` would read the number that was inputted.

The following is my current PHP form:

```
<form id="Corporate" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Head Count<span>*</span></p>
    <input min="0" id='' type="number" value placeholder="Enter the Headcount" name="head_count" required>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Square Footage<span>*</span></p>
    <input min="0" type="number" value placeholder="Enter the Square Footage" name="sq_ft" required> 

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>What's your territory?<span>*</span></p>
        <select name="territory" required>
            <option value="">Select One</option>
            <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>Email<span>*</span></p>
        <input style="width:100%;" type="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p style="text-align:center;"><i>Don't forget to hit submit below!</i></p>
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
            <input class="BudgetSubmit" type="submit" name="submit">
        </div>
</form>

< ?php
     //run math depending on user input
            $head_count = null; // I previously set this to be a random number Ex: $head_count = 55; for testing purposes
            $taskMeetings_int = $head_count * 1.9;
            $taskMeetings_low = 520 * $taskMeetings_int;
            $taskMeetings_high = 1050 * $taskMeetings_int;

            $square_footage = null; // I previously set this to be a random number Ex: $square_footage = 13000; for testing purposes
            $conf_tables_int = $square_footage/5000;
            $conf_tables_low = 1050 * $conf_tables_int * .1;
            $conf_tables_high = 2000 * $conf_tables_int * .16;

?>
```

Would I need to set a id within the form for the headcount and square footage? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** My apologies, the following is what appears once the form is submitted:

```
<?php

    //my resource library function
    function mrllinks($link,$title,$image){
        echo "<p><a target='_blank' href='$link' title='$title'><img style='width:100%;' src='$image'/></p>";
    }

    function RepLayout1($link,$image,$name){
        echo "<div class='flex-item'>
                    <a target='_blank' href='$link'><img src='$image'/></a>                
             </div>";
    }



    // displays results after initial submission
    if($submitted){
        $lowTotal = $taskMeetings_low + $guestLounge_low + $gen_tables_low + $workspaceStation_low + $workspaceOffice_low + $techErgo_low + $ancillary_low + $taskLighting_low + $soundMasking_low;
        $highTotal = $taskMeetings_high + $guestLounge_high + $gen_tables_high + $workspaceStation_high + $workspaceOffice_high + $techErgo_high + $ancillary_high + $taskLighting_high + $soundMasking_high;
      ?>


      <div class="col-lg-12 corporatecalculator_answer">
            <p style="margin:0px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;"><b style="color:#000;">Total estimated budget (Based on list prices):</b><?php echo '<b style="color:#EE3B33;"> &#36;'.number_format($lowTotal).' - '.number_format($highTotal) .'</b>';?><p>
            <hr>
             <div class="BudgetResultsBorderHeader"><b style="color:#000;">Task & Meeting Chairs:</b><?php echo '&nbsp; &#36;'.number_format($taskMeetings_low).' - '.number_format($taskMeetings_high);?></div>
              <?php if ($territory == "Louisiana"){?>
          <div class=" flex-container "> <?php
              RepLayout1('https://stackoverflow.com','/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/2.jpg','Stack Overlflow');  ?>
          </div>
        <?php  
              }     
                else if($territory == "Mississippi"){?>
          <div class=" flex-container "> <?php
              RepLayout1('https://stackoverflow.com','/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/3.jpg','Stack Overlflow');  ?>
          </div>             
        <?php
                }

        } ?> 


        </div>

        <?php
    } 

?>
```

Comment: What and where do you get error? Also setting var to `null` will actually make it null and not *read the number that was inputted*. Also your HTML has nothing to do with PHP part.

Comment: @Justinas       Thank you for letting me know that my HTML portion is not causing the error and that setting var to null makes it not read the number that was inputted. The exact error that I am getting is that when I enter the numbers that I manually input for both variables, the math results are displaying zero. In this case, would I set the variables to be ' '; ?

Comment: I'm not getting how your PHP would get the values from your form? Is there parts missing in your code? If not, you need to read up on the difference between Server Side (PHP) and Client Side (HTML/JS). Btw, you're currently setting a variable ($head_count) to null, then you're trying to use it as a number? That would be treated as zero and multiplying using zero will _always_ result in zero.

Comment: @Gilgamesh90 I don't get it. Where is your *result*? If you put `$head_count` and `$square_footage` as empty (0, '', null, etc) than all your further calculations will be `0 * ### == 0`

Comment: You are using a bunch of variables in PHP,  but you're not showing us where you define or setting any of them. Are they magic? Simply popping into existence?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you, I added the second form that displays the results once the submit button is set in the first form. My mistake was setting  ($head_count) and ($square_footage) to null. Instead of setting them to null, how would I set them each variable to the input that was entered?

Comment: I recommend that you start by reading the manual about the basics for using forms in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php. This is PHP 101.

Comment: @Justinas The result appears in a second php form that appears once the submit button is hit in on the first form and I added it once I realized I forgot to include it in the original post.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you once again, as this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The actual results appeared once I removed the null for both variables and set it to be:

```
    $head_count = (int)$_POST['head_count'];
    $square_footage = (int)$_POST['sq_ft'];
```

Thank you @MagnusEriksson and @Justinas for the PHP 101.